# How can I get the number of OverDue tasks based on date field in Power BI?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi, dax

I need to create a Measure that would display the number of tasks that are over due, based on today's date.

[image]
[image]

So basically I need to translate this into DAX in power BI?

```
SUM(If DueDate is greater then today then count it as OverDueTask)
```

I tried to do something like that but when trying to display it it says:
 Cant display the visual

```
OverDueTasks = CALCULATE(SUM(TotalCounts[DueDate]), FILTER(TotalCounts,[DueDate]>TODAY()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your formula and the issue appears to be the `SUM`. You are summing dates so Power BI is going to treat them like dates, but the formula goes past the threshold for dates. Change the `SUM` to a `COUNT` and it should work.

```
OverDueTasks = CALCULATE(
    COUNT(TotalCounts[DueDate]), 
    FILTER(
        TotalCounts,
        [DueDate] > TODAY() &&
        [CompletedDate] = ""
    )
)
```

Comment: Joe, if I also need to add another condition such as CompletedDate have to be empty. So DueDate > TODAY & CompletedDate = ' '. Can I put this condition in the same FILTER? Or this function only accepts one parameter?

Comment: @Oleg The `FILTER` function can take any number of conditions; just separate each with `&&`. I've updated my answer with your additional condition.

Answer (score 1):

you should first create a calculated column with formula

```
=IF(Table1[DueDate]>TODAY()|1|0)
```

Then a measure to sum this up

```
Overdue:=SUM(Table1[Calculated Column 1])
```

[image: DAX screenshots]